# progress bar for general non-looping script, or using multiple processes to write to stdout

Tags: bash, shell-script, python

How do I make a spinning wheel or progress bar that measures the progress of a very general script and I don't need or want to run it over anything looping or iterable? It doesn't need to be anywhere near exact in terms of measurement.

I've seen many examples online- but they all depend on and consume iterables or loops. I don't want to operate at that level. I don't want to interleaven code with progress bar code. When I implement or try figure out how to implement their examples of wheels and bars, my script blocks and none of my actual code gets run.

I would be fine running multiple threads if they can both print to the same terminal/stdout. Then how would I do that? It can be in python or bash, as my bash script is calling a python script. If I can manually generate a new process or thread, and capture it's reference (id), I can have it print to stdout and then when the main worker thread is finished, as a teardown it can kill the second display process. Would this work? Is this the right paradigm?

Comment: this is a simple spinner that has been used in shell for ages.  seems like what you are looking for
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498304/using-bash-to-display-a-progress-indicator